# Why is psutil reporting 0.0% CPU usage some of the time?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

I'm attempting to use the psutil python library to measure CPU utilisation over time for the current process (`os.getpid()`). The script is intended to print values of the CPU usage over each 1 second interval. The simulated average load is intended to be quite low (~1%), to be similar to the real process I will measure.

The problem is that psutil seems to report values of 0.0% usage some of the time, which doesn't make sense over a 1s interval (note the 0.1s sleep time in the simulated load function). Can someone please help me to understand the values psutil is reporting or point out if I'm misusing it in some way.

Thanks!

### versions

python = 3.10.8
psutil = 5.9.0

```
import time
import random
import psutil
import threading

test_time = 10
start_time = time.perf_counter()

def simulate_load():
    while time.perf_counter() - start_time < test_time:
        c = 0
        for _ in range(350):
            c += random.randint(0, 5)
        time.sleep(0.1)

def measure_load():
    log = []
    this_process = psutil.Process()
    this_process.cpu_affinity([15])
    this_process.cpu_percent(interval=0)
    while time.perf_counter() - start_time < test_time:
       log.append(this_process.cpu_percent(interval=0))
       time.sleep(1)
    return log

background_thread = threading.Thread(target=simulate_load)
background_thread.start()

print(measure_load())
```

### output

[0.0, 1.6, 1.5, 0.0, 1.6, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.1]

Comment: Recall that threads running Python code won't run simultaneously due to the GIL, so trying to use a Python thread to measure the CPU usage of another Python thread will probably not give you realistic results. Instead, maybe spawn a subprocess that does a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if it could be something to do with the GIL. But psutil should be measuring the process usage, so shouldn't that be the sum total of all threads, regardless of any multithreading/GIL issues?

Answer (score 0):

`range(350)` is way too low for you to notice something on a modern computer.
Try with `range(1e6)` for example.

For 350, I got: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

For 1e6 : [186.3, 81.1, 80.1, 89.4, 89.4, 90.4, 79.5, 80.5, 78.5, 82.6]

Interesting numbers and orders of magnitude [reference table](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html#answers).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. In the question I stated that I need to measure a very low usage ~1%. This is why I am using range(350).

Comment: Also, please note that I set the CPU affinity in the example, so the usage should not be expected to go above 100%, even for large simulated loads.

Comment: My bad, I did not pay attention to the "very low usage". However, for your second point, I kept your code for testing (only changed 15 to 0 as I have only 4 CPUs on my machine - running on WSL2 Ubuntu for information).

Comment: Thanks, I spotted that the sleep call should come before the cpu_percent call in the while loop. The initial value was very noisy before as there was very little time between calls to cpu_percent. This doesn't fix the main problem though, just the initial reported value.